# CodeIgniter Simple Form Validation Return Blank Page

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm learning PHP Codeigniter, especially on Form-Validation. All of my source code are copy pasted from [their website](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) and **nothing changed (it just copy-paste**). This Form Validation seems pretty simple, However every time i click the "submit button" then appear blank page. The Codes are :

***MyForm.php*** **(View)**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('form'); ?>

<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Password</h5>
<input type="text" name="password" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Password Confirm</h5>
<input type="text" name="passconf" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Email Address</h5>
<input type="text" name="email" value="" size="50" />

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

***FormSuccess.php* (Success Page):**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Your form was successfully submitted!</h3>

<p><?php echo anchor('form', 'Try it again!'); ?></p>

</body>
</html>
```

And ***Form.php* (Controller)** :

```
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required',
                    array('required' => 'You must provide a %s.')
            );
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                    $this->load->view('MyForm');
            }
            else
            {
                    $this->load->view('FormSuccess');
            }
    }
}
```

If my code works, after i click submit button then **it should go to Success Page** (formsuccess.php) but now it return blank page.

**The Form SS :**

[image]

I've tried to change **webserver to XAMPP**, but still face same problem...

Thanks before, for your help...

Comment: are you running the php from a server, like wamp?

Comment: @Victoria Yes, i'm running php using wamp...

Comment: Change your file name to `form.php`

Comment: And which version if CI you use??

Comment: @Saty, i've tried but still failed. I'm using CI 3.0 and WAMP 2.5

Comment: edit $this->load->view('myform'); to $this->load->view('MyForm'); because your file name is MyForm.php

Comment: what is your php version?

Comment: Post the url here after you submit the form.

Comment: @monace19 about:blank (chrome)

Comment: try removing array('required' => 'You must provide a %s.')

Comment: @monace19  i've removed all code rules, but still same...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97261/discussion-between-monace19-and-user2226388).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error, i found solution. Here're my changes to code :

**Controller, Form.php**

```
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required',
                array('required' => 'You must provide a %s.')
        );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**View, MyForm.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<form action="<?php base_url();?>form" method="POST">

<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Password</h5>
<input type="text" name="password" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Password Confirm</h5>
<input type="text" name="passconf" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Email Address</h5>
<input type="text" name="email" value="" size="50" />

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```